# Testing NativeScript application on emulator and device in parallel

Tags: angular, testing, nativescript

I am working on angular NS app. I want to test 2 users behaviour by launching independent app on emulator and independent one on device. Currently i cannot find way (except duplicating project phisically) how to do this.
I was trying to launch app on emulator and then via sidekick launch on device. It launches but device gets emualtors build and emulator stops syncing.

So is there a way how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open a separate terminal window and invoke `tns run` from there. I use that approach to test with multiple devices.

Comment: Yes, this works. However from time to time - not sure when, one version owerwrites boths devices...

Answer (score 0):

Or, build a package with Sidekick, transfer it to your device, install it and run it.